# number(X) as function parameter or return value generates PLS 00103 error

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

I have the following function definition:

```
create or replace FUNCTION checkXML
 (idx in number(19)) 
 return number(19)
is 
...
```

But when I compile it, am getting the following errors,

```
Error(2,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the 
following: := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for 
"(" to continue. 
Error(3,15): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the 
following:     . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character    
deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache
```

Comment: I reverted your changes fixing the code and modified the question to focus more on the original issue. If you're asking about an error, please don't fix the code in the question, as this invalidates the answers. And please don't ask new questions using the comments - rather post it as a separate question. It also doesn't hurt to remove / change a few lines of your code to try to narrow down the issue (just make sure your final version actually causes the same error) (which leads to a way more useful question with much less code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function declaraction to be

```
create or replace FUNCTION checkXML
  (idx in number) 
  return number
```

PL/SQL doesn't accept length or precision specifiers on parameters or return types.

Share and enjoy.